# Adding dimension, coordinates and attributes to dataArray

Tags: attributes, coordinates, dimension, expansion, python-xarray

I am working on a function that takes one `xarray.DataArray` `sfc_p` and an `int` `vert_res` (where the first one represents a surface pressure field and the second one a number of vertical levels), which computes pressure on all vertical levels, adds coordinates, dimension and attributes and outputs the `xarray.DataArray` `pressure`.

The computation works fine, but my problem is the following:
An example for `sfc_p` could be this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'sp' (time: 1, ens: 51, lat: 66, lon: 131)>
dask.array<shape=(1, 51, 66, 131), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1, 1, 66, 131)>
Coordinates:                                                                               
  * lon      (lon) float32 -100.0 -99.0 -98.0 -97.0 -96.0 -95.0 -94.0 -93.0 ...            
  * lat      (lat) float32 85.0 84.0 83.0 82.0 81.0 80.0 79.0 78.0 77.0 76.0 ...           
  * ens      (ens) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...             
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2016-11-02T12:00:00                                     
Attributes:                                                                                
    units:          Pa                                                                     
    long_name:      Surface pressure                                                       
    standard_name:  surface_air_pressure                                                   
    cf_short_name:  sp                                                                     
    short_name:     sp                                                                     
    grid_type:      regular_ll   <xarray.DataArray 'sp' (time: 1, ens: 51, lat: 66, lon: 131)>
```

Now I wish the output array to take over most of these properties, with an additional dimension (after `time` and `ensemble`) and coordinate `hybrid` which is simply `range(1, vert_res + 1)` and to have some of the attributes modified, like

```
<xarray.DataArray 'sp' (time: 1, ens: 51, hybrid:137, lat: 66, lon: 131)>
dask.array<shape=(1, 51, 137, 66, 131), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1, 1, 137, 66, 131)>
Coordinates:                                                                               
  * lon      (lon) float32 -100.0 -99.0 -98.0 -97.0 -96.0 -95.0 -94.0 -93.0 ...            
  * lat      (lat) float32 85.0 84.0 83.0 82.0 81.0 80.0 79.0 78.0 77.0 76.0 ...    
  * hybrid   (hybrid) int32 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...       
  * ens      (ens) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...             
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2016-11-02T12:00:00                                     
Attributes:                                                                                
    units:          Pa                                                                     
    long_name:      modified                                                       
    standard_name:  modified                                                  
    cf_short_name:  modified                                                                    
    short_name:     modified                                                                    
    grid_type:      modified
```

I am currently computing a np.ndarray `pressureVals` (with the right output shape) for the values and then initialize my output `xarray.DataArray` with this.
But even after hours of reading through the `xArray` documentation, I havent found a way to achieve this simple task of adding the information and metadata and I think I am missing something completely basic. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

To change the attributes it is
`da.attrs['long_name'] = 'new_long_name'`

You may be able to use http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.expand_dims.html to add a dimension take a look at the numpy doc as well https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html